# How to find out user defined function in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am creating sql data dictionary.I am using sql server 2005.I wanted to know user defined function.I Expanded database.Under Programability :- Function:- table value function and scalar value function.

Comment: It is not clear what *"ow to find out user defined function"* means.

Comment: some functions are system generated like max(),min().But some time used define or create function.I wanted to find out that.

Comment: @Sherin - But your question says how to do that. Do you mean you want a query that lists all functions?

Comment: If not query,just tell me that it is under table value and scalar value function.Is it right?I want to see from design point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are asking how to list all functions programatically

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name, 
       name,
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) AS definition
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc IN ('SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION','SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION',
                  'SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION')
```